# Samba min protocol SMB3, nmap report SMBv1

Tags: 18.04, samba, nmap

I use a Linux system with Ubuntu 18.04.5.
Te file `/etc/samba/smb.conf` contains the rules:

```
client min protocol = SMB3
```

and

```
smb encrypt = required
```

The command `nmap -p445 -Pn -vvv --script smb-protocols` on this system gives (between others) the following output:

```
  Host script results:
  | smb-protocols:
  | dialects:
  | NT LM 0.12 (SMBv1) [dangerous, but default]
  | 2.02
  | 2.10
  | 3.00
  | 3.02
  |_ 3.11
```

Is that in contrast to each other?

In Samba it is set that the minimum SMB protocol is 3. `nmap` reports the dangerous SMBv1 protocol anyway.

Can the Ubuntu system still be accessed with SMBv1?

Answer (score 0):

The smb-protocols nmap script checks to see which smb dialects are present on the Samba **server**.

client min protocol sets the minimum smb dialect that server can use to connect to another server not the minimum dialects that a client to this server can use.

By default the version of samba used in Ubuntu 18.04 sets the server min to NT1 ( smbv1 ) and the max to SMBv3.

If you want to restrict access to this server to SMB3 and SMB3 only you need to set the server min protocol:

```
server min protocol = SMB3
```

*Note: there are sub-variants to this dialect:

SMB3_00: Windows 8

SMB3_02: Windows 8.1

SMB3_10: early Windows 10

SMB3_11: Windows 10

By default SMB3 in smb.conf selects the SMB3_11 variant.*

Comment: Setting the parameter client min protocol = SMB3 give:

Host script results:
| smb-protocols: 
|   dialects: 
|_    3.11

This resolves the contradiction.